# Add a Shared View Folder using the Spark View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I am trying to register a shared view folder using the spark view engine.

The code I currently have:

```
var folder = @"C:\MySharedViews";
settings.AddViewFolder(ViewFolderType.FileSystem, new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"subfolder", "shared"},
    {"basePath", folder}
});
```

works if I have a subfolder "Shared" at "C:\MySharedViews\Shared" but how can I make "C:\MySharedViews" my shared views folder?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used spark - however it looks like you are specifying you want it to look in C:\MySharedViews\Shared

```
{"subfolder", "shared"}
```

Can't you remove that line? Or if not an empty string or null value?

Comment: I get the same results with or without {"subfolder", "shared"}

Comment: And if it's null or an empty string?

Comment: yes, when you create a view folder it looks for either sub folder with the controller name or a sub folder called "Shared". I'm trying to make the top level view folder act like the shared folder.